# how Abstract Calendar class's getInstance method returns a calendar Object

Tags: java

Hi I know that Abstract classes can't be instantiated. But in Java API Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) the calendar class is an Abstract class and there is a static `getInstance()` method which returns a Calendar object. If the Abstract calendar object can't be instantiated, so how this method returns a Calendar object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Calendar.getInstance()` returns an instance of one of the concrete classes `GregorianCalendar`, `BuddhistCalendar` or `JapaneseImperialCalendar` depending on the locale. Each of theses classes is a Calendar because they all extend abstract `Calendar`. It's like here

```
abstract class A {
    public static A getInstance() {
          return new B();
    }
}

class B extends A {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It returns a class that extends Calendar, in this case java.util.GregorianCalendar, which can be checked with

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(cal.getClass());
```

A subclass can be stored within a variable of the parent class, even if the parent class cannot be instantiated directly.

Comment: So GregorianCalendar is also a Calendar type because it extends GregorianCalendar. Right?

Comment: Yes, extending a class makes it a child of the original class, so it is a GregorianCalendar, as well as a Calendar. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a singleton instance for each type of the calendar.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

`getInstance()` is a custom method and if you look at the jdk source, it is returning `GregorianCalendar` (or some other implementation of `java.util.Calendar` class).

I think you confused yourself thinking that `getInstance()` is [Reflection method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29)?